# Why does QImage's pixel function goes out of scope?

Tags: python, qt, qimage

I have image of height = 394 and width = 700 in other word row = 394 and col = 700. But when I try to access the pixel value at given pixel by `grey_img.pixel(row, col)` I get out of range error. For some reason `grey_img.pixel(col, row)` works.

Can someone help me figure out, why do I get the out of range error when doing `grey_img.pixel(row, col)` and not the other way round?

I thought the index would go as (row, col) because

(0,0),(0,1),(0,2)...(0,699)

(1,0),(1,1),(1,2)...(1,699)

...

(393,0),(393,1),(393,2)...(393,699)

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, qGray

# read jpg image and convert it to grey scale.
grey_img = QImage("test_img.jpg").convertToFormat(QImage.Format_Grayscale8)

# print the pixel value of each pixel form the grey scale image.
img_height = grey_img.height()
img_width = grey_img.width()
print("height = ", img_height)
print("width  = ", img_width)

# height =  394
# width  =  700

for row in range(0, img_height):
    for col in range(0, img_width):
        # works
        gray_val = qGray(grey_img.pixel(col, row))

        # does not work
        # gives out of range error
        # QImage::pixel: coordinate (179,482) out of range
        # gray_val = qGray(grey_img.pixel(row, col))
```

Comment: It think you are confusing the order of x and y? The usual order is (x,y) (i.e. (width, height)), not the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QImage::pixel` function takes as argument `(int x, int y)` as `(column, row)` values